# Wiremock: how to mock endpoint that returns InputStream?

Tags: java, rest, inputstream, junit4, wiremock

I have a working code that requests an endpoint and read its response this way (the stream is a PDF):

```
private Response readResponseBody(Response response) throws IOException {
  InputStream inputStream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
  try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    if (inputStream != null) {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int len;
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) { //error this line with wiremock
        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }
    }
  }
  //other stuffs...
}
```

I tried to mock that enpoint using wiremock at test environment using JUnit4 @Rule, this way:

```
byte[] pdfFile = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("file.pdf").toURI()));
stubFor(
  get(urlPathMatching(mockPath))
  .withHeader("Authorization", equalTo(mockedToken))
  .willReturn(aResponse()
    .withStatus(200)
    .withBody(pdfFile)));
```

But when I request the mocked endpoint, I'm not able to read the InputStream, I get this error at the referred line above:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
```

Which is the right way to mock an endpoint that returns an InputStream using Wiremock?

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time reading Wiremock documentation, I figured out what's wrong. One way to create a stub that downloads some file is to put that file under `src/test/resources/__files` directory, if I'm going to use the method:

```
withBodyFile("file.pdf")
```

By default, this is the directory where Wiremock server will look to get any file to be *downloaded* through the stubs. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128295/11625850), I would guess that you can just return the file path as the response body.

```
  .willReturn(aResponse()
    .withStatus(200)
    .withBodyFile("/path/to/pdf/file")));
```

If that does not work, I would suggest adding a content-type header to the response. Assuming the file is a pdf, that would be

```
.withHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
```

Comment: I tried your way. Now the error has changed. I got: 
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 2674; received: 0...
And wiremock returned status 500! I tested the given path with File.exists()

Comment: I suspect the path is not arbitrary or absolute, but must be a *relative* path to `src/test/resources/__files`

Comment: Additionally, you can change where WireMock looks for files by using the methods listed here: http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/#file-locations